# How can I prevent os.system from causing "ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment"?

Tags: python

When I run...

```
os.system("firefox --private-window https://www.example.com")
```

I get this message in my terminal...

```
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
```

...which seems to prevent the rest of my script from operating properly.

I have read that many developers seem to try to avoid using `os.system`, but my script failed to run properly when I tried to use `subprocess.run`; therefore I used `os.system`.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1378056

Answer (score 0):

The message:

`ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.`

comes from the mesa library because firefox overrides its default.
See [this report bug at mozilla.org](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1744389)

I wonder if this prevents your script to run properly. In contrast, using `os.system` should block the script as `os.system` waits for the command to
be completed. Unless if `firefox` puts itself in background (this is the case
when there is a `firefox` process already running).

Comment: You seem to have grasped the problem. What I actually learned is that the error message appears sometimes but not others regardless of whether I use `os.system` or  `subprocess.run`. I have no idea why. A few days ago I "googled it" and found that indeed it's a Firefox bug.